# Scan string and integer from file in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to put values from a file into variables. I have a `fruits.txt` file with the following data.

```
bananas,5
apples,3
kiwi,7
```

The comma separates the name of the fruit from the price. My goal is to put the name into a string called fruit and the price into an `int` called price, move the file pointer to the next line, then print it.

```
FILE * fptr = fopen("fruit.txt", "r");
char fruit[10];
int price = 0;

fscanf(fptr, "%s,%d\n", fruit, &price);
printf("%s,%d\n", fruit, price);

fclose(fptr);
```

Is what I have so far. However, my output is `bananas,5,0`. It seems like it is doing the first part correctly but then adding another ,0. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682699/reading-integers-and-strings-from-a-file-in-c) an hour ago.

Comment: You could try `while(fscanf(fptr, "%9s,%d", fruit, &price) == 2)` but please be more generous with the size of the string, and, restrict the input length. And there is no need to pick off the trailing newline: both `%s` and `%d` ignore leading whitespace.

Comment: & you should have edited it instead asking a new one to the same topic.

Comment: @WeatherVane `%s` eats delimiter too so he should better use `[^,]`.

Answer (score 4):

> my output is 'bananas,5,0'. It seems like it is doing the first part
>   correctly but then adding another ,0.

Because `%s` eats your delimiter(`,`) too, hence putting complete `bananas,5` into  `fruit` variable.

If you had checked the return value from `fscanf` it was just returning `1` and it was not reading `%d` into `price` variable.

**Solution:**

You could just use `[^,]` to read the string using `,` as delimiter and put `fscanf` in `while` loop checking return value for 2.

Sample code.

```
FILE * fptr = fopen("fruit.txt", "r");
char fruit[10];
int price = 0;

while(fscanf(fptr, "%9[^,],%d%*[\n]", fruit, &price) == 2)
    printf("%s,%d\n", fruit, price);

fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: @User9123 `%9` means `fscanf` should only read max of 9 char. That is done to avoid buffer overflow since you have declared `fruit[10]`

Comment: @User9123 and `%*` means read the input but do not assign it to any arguments in `fscanf`. That is done to eat up the input until reaching end of the line.

Comment: @Swordfish my comment got removed I don't know how.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I'm innocent.

Comment: @Swordfish yes you are! Some moderator must have removed it.